# boost local time is not updated after changing the time zone until the program is restarted

Tags: c++, linux, timezone, boost-date-time

boost version 1.71.0, OS Ubuntu 20

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto utc_now = boost::date_time::second_clock<boost::posix_time::ptime>::universal_time();
        auto now = boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<boost::posix_time::ptime>::utc_to_local(utc_now);
        std::cout << "now: " << to_simple_string(now) << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running this code, I change the time zone using `timedatectl` and these changes are not displayed in the program until I restart it:

```
./program
now: 2024-Mar-12 12:30:09
# in another terminal change the timezone: sudo timedatectl set-timezone <some new timezone>
now: 2024-Mar-12 12:30:19 # the same local time, was not updated
```

And if you run the program again, the local time is updated:

```
./program
now: 2024-Mar-12 06:30:25 # new local time
```

How to make the local time updated while the program is running?

Comment: If C++20 is available to you, [`std::chrono::current_zone()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/current_zone) solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source code of boost::datetime, [utc_to_local()](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/boost-1.71.0/include/boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp) calls an internal function called [localtime()](https://github.com/boostorg/date_time/blob/boost-1.71.0/include/boost/date_time/c_time.hpp), which in turns call the POSIX function [localtime_r()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime).

As specified on the manpage in the notes sections,

> According to POSIX.1-2004, localtime() is required to behave as though
> tzset(3) was called, while localtime_r() does not have this
> requirement. For portable code tzset(3) should be called before
> localtime_r().

In conclusion, the glibc library function `localtime_r()` does not behave as one would expect, you need to call `tzset()` everytime to retrieve expected result when the timezone has been changed. Boost library does not (for optimization purpose perhaps), hence you must call it yourself, and wrap it inside #ifdefs if you intend to write portable code.

I do not know if the behavior of the boost function (i.e. not taking into account timezone changes) is a bug or a "feature".